# "Accept" a comment?

Tags: feature-request

I noticed that sometimes the correct answer is inside a comment, and the asker have to answer him/herself quoting the comment.

How about make it possible to accept a comment? Of course the time that must elapse before you can accept a comment should be much greater than answers.

Comment: How do you feel about this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238511/can-i-put-a-javascript-time-limit-on-an-iframe

Comment: Noo no no no. Comments are *comments*. If the poster doesn't want to leave an answer then that's up to them. If they really don't want to convert it to an answer then you could answer your own question using that comment as the text, credit the poster and accept that. But comments are just that - comments.

Comment: @JonW That pretty well summarizes the answer in the proposed dupe, covering most of the points it does.

Comment: You can post that comment as an answer and do it with Community wiki user.

Comment: Can the user accept @JonW's comment? \*runs\*

Comment: When an answer is left as a comment, it often means that the solution was trivial. Adding a full answer validates the question when it should really be closed. The comment is a compromise: Give the asker what he/she wants, but don't clutter the site with useless questions/answers.

Comment: @JonW: I would have said that an answer is what answers to a question.

Comment: @Servy: about Yannis' answer to the other question, the fact a commenter could not agree to make his/her comment an answer is true, but SO could simply require the approval of the comment owner, as for edits.

Comment: @LucasMalor Sounds like you should be posting that on that answer, not here.

Comment: @Jamiec: You see what should happen here is that you copy my comment as an actual answer, it then gets accepted. (And then I moan and complain about you stealing my answer and getting all the credit).

Comment: I've seen the asker ask the commenter to post the comment as an answer, which then gets accepted by the asker. Make sense?